# How to get Webform Radio Option Value as a token value for email template?

Tags: 8, webforms, tokens

I am trying to use my webform's radio field to choose between two departments, let's call them ABCDE and XYZ.  On the webform display that the user sees, I want them to show up as ABCDE and XYZ.  When I send the form as an email, I need these to show up as a similar 4 digit word such as ABCD and WXYZ.

I attempted to do this by setting the "Option Value" as the hidden 4 digit word and then have the actual text show up as "Option Text".

In the email template, I have this printed out as: [webform_submission:values:radioButtonName]

This prints it out as the "Option Text" (ABCDE and XYZ) rather than the "Option Value" (4 digit ABCD or WXYZ) that I am looking for.  Is there a way to print the "Option Value" of this radio button instead?  I assume its done by changing the word "values" to something else, but I haven't been able to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the `:raw` suffix to the token and change `[webform_submission:values:radioButtonName]` to `[webform_submission:values:radioButtonName:raw]`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for your response.